# Make some forums appear in Gmail primary tab

Tags: gmail

How do I make postings, from some of the forums I am subscribed to, appear in the Primary tab?

Comment: Are you asking about email notifications for responses to posts you've made on some 3rd-party forum? I don't know how you would "subscribe to" a forum with Gmail otherwise....

Comment: Drag and drop them to the primary tab.

Comment: @Sathya: But doesn't that _remove_ the forum categorisation, from an otherwise forum related email? (To be honest, this is one of the reasons why I disabled categorisation/tabs in Gmail... it creates more work and failure to get notified of any non-primary email.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the comments mention, you can't drag and drop into the Primary tab unless you want to always categorize emails from that forum as "Primary"

What you could try doing is setting up a filter that automatically stars an email from the forums email address (e.g. forum-group@example.com). This will also allow you to refine which forum emails are starred (e.g. only contain the words "lorem ipsum" etc)

Once you get it so that Gmail stars email from your forum, click on the Gear menu and select `Configure Inbox`

From there you can select the option to add any Starred email to your primary inbox. This should allow you to keep the forum categorization and still have it show up in the Primary tab.

[image]